# Not able to create sharded collection

Tags: database, mongodb, sharding

I have a mongodb Cluster with one config node(replication),one query node , and one shard node(with replication).

I tried to create sharded collection but it is giving me error:

command that i ran :

```
use exampleDB
sh.enableSharding("exampleDB")
```

Output:

```
{
    "ok" : 1,
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1611723057, 4),
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1611723057, 4),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    }
}
```

Now creating a collection :

```
 db.exampleCollection.ensureIndex( { _id : "hashed" } )
```

Output :

```
{
    "raw" : {
        "shardSet/clb1pidnmd3.ccsm.in:27017" : {
            "createdCollectionAutomatically" : true,
            "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
            "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
            "commitQuorum" : "votingMembers",
            "ok" : 1
        }
    },
    "ok" : 1,
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1611723093, 3),
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1611723093, 3),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    }
}
```

Now sharding collection

```
sh.shardCollection( "exampleDB.exampleCollection", { "_id" : "hashed" } )
```

Output :

```
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Shard shard0000 not found",
    "code" : 70,
    "codeName" : "ShardNotFound",
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1611723116, 5),
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1611723116, 5),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    }
}
```

Not able to figure out what to do now

Comment: Review this tutorial and see if you have missed any of the steps: [Deploy a Sharded Cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/index.html). Also, include the version of the MongoDB.

Comment: What do you get from `db.getSiblingDB("admin").runCommand("getShardMap")` and `sh.status()`? Also try `db.adminCommand( {shardingState: 1} )` on the shard node.

Answer (score 0):

Before these steps, you need to have first added the shard servers through below command in Mongo.

```
sh.addShard("shard0000/IP:Port")
```